# Retrofit - HTTP FAILED: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed when I try to refresh token

Tags: java, android, token, retrofit2

I need to refresh token via Retrofit API. I want to do it in Interceptor. But when I run app, it's can't finish request. It returns HTTP FAILED: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed.
I have researched a lot of information, but I can't find solution.

My RestClient

```
public class RestClient {

/* Singleton init */
private static RestClient instance = new RestClient();

public static RestClient getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "JWT ";
private String token;

public void setToken(String token) {

    this.token = token;
    api = create();
}

public void refreshToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public String getTokenHeader() {
    return TOKEN_PREFIX + token;
}

private API api;

private RestClient() {
    api = create();
}

public API getApi() {
    return api;
}

private API create() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);


    if (token != null) {
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor(new AuthInterceptor(this, getTokenHeader()));
    }
    OkHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    return retrofit.create(API.class);
}}
```

my AuthInterceptor. I use it for token refresh

```
public class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {
private String authValue;
private RestClient restClient;

public AuthInterceptor(RestClient restClient, String authValue) {
    this.restClient = restClient;
    this.authValue = authValue;
}


@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();

    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", authValue);

    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    if (response.body().string().equals("jwt expired")) {
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
        loginRequest.fbToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken();
        Call<LoginResponse> call = restClient.getApi().refreshToken(loginRequest);
        restClient.refreshToken(call.execute().body().token);
        Request newRequest = chain.request();
        newRequest = newRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", restClient.getTokenHeader()).build();

        response = chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
    return response;

}}
```

Comment: You probably need to use authenticator for new token . https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
ResponseBody responseBodyCopy = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE);
responseBodyCopy.string();
```

it works for me